# I got an error for the last 3 if else statements

Tags: java, helper

```
if (annual <= lowincome && aChar == 'S')
    owe = annual * .25;
else if ( annual > lowincome || annual < medincome && aChar == 'S')
    owe = annual * .50;
else if (annual > medincome && Char == 'S')
    owe = annual * .75;
else if (aChar == 'M' && annual <= lowincome)
    owe = annual *.24;
else if(annual > low income || annual < medincome && aChar == 'M')
    owe = annual * .49;
else if(annual > medincome && Char == 'M')
    owe = annual * .74;
```

I want the user to input if they are married or single then go though calculation after finding out there annual income.I get this error

```
TaxReturn.java:54: error: ')' expect
if(annual > low income || annual < medincome && aChar == 'M')
                                           ^
TaxReturn.java:54: error: not a statement
if(annual > low income || annual < medincome && aChar == 'M')
                                                   ^
TaxReturn.java:54: error: ';' expect
if(annual > low income || annual < medincome && aChar == 'M')

TaxReturn.java:56: error: 'else' without 'if'
else 
                            ^
TaxReturn.java:68: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}       
^
5 errors
```

Comment: [tag:homework]? **This tag is OBSOLETE**.

Comment: Why you don't like braces? Anyways, is this your complete code?

Comment: OMG too much of if-else-if-else..!! there are errors in your code, I suggest you to dissect one by one, you will learn where you have done error :)

Comment: _ALWAYS_ use braces when nesting so many ifs

Answer (score 6):

```
if(annual > low income || annual < medincome && aChar == 'M')
```

should be

```
if(annual > lowincome || annual < medincome && aChar == 'M')
```

Neither `low` nor `income` are recognized as declared variables.

Answer (score 1):

You should use brackets for give perfect meaning on your conditions...

```
if ( annual  >  low income  ||(  annual  <  medincome  &&  aChar  == 'M' )) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

you should make this a helper method that returns the owe amount, this will allow you to get rid of that nasty nesting business.  If you have nested more than three if statements, you need to reconsider how you are going about solving the problem.  I assure you, you will lose points for that.

that being said, your code is bombing out due to the space between "low" and "income"...should be "lowincome".

here's an example of how you might consider reorganizing your code...

```
public BigDecimal getOwed(BigDecimal annual){
    if (annual <= lowincome && aChar == 'S'){
        return owe = annual * .25;
    }

    if ( annual > lowincome || annual < medincome && aChar == 'S'){
           return owe = annual * .50;
    }

    if (annual > medincome && Char == 'S'){
        return owe = annual * .75;
    }
    /*go through all your cases in this fashion
    .
    .
    .
    handle the case that it doesnt match any (should never occur).
    */

}
```

this way is cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

this comes from your error trace

```
if(annual > low income || annual < medincome && aChar == 'M')
```

you cant have space inside variable, like in your `low income`

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this code:

```
if (annual > medincome && Char == 'S'){
    return owe = annual * .75;
}
```

be this:

```
if (annual > medincome && aChar == 'S'){
    return owe = annual * .75;
}
```

It looks like you aren't evaluating your variable aChar consistently. You do this in your last "else if" statement as well.